# Is there any limit in patent image height and width?

Tags: provisional-application

I'm about to file a provisional patent.

Some of my patent flowcharts diagrams looks way bigger.

Is there any limit in patent image height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the law 37 CFR 1.84,the size of the sheets on which drawings are made must be:
(1) 21.0 cm. by 29.7 cm. (DIN size A4), or
(2) 21.6 cm. by 27.9 cm. (8 1/2 by 11 inches).

A long view can be sub-divided into single or multiple sheets if there is no loss in facility of understanding the view

Comment: id wonder whether it matters for provisional application? As aren't these not really looked at? 37 CFR 1.84 says nothing about provisional applications. The question Id think would be rather if an incorrect drawing per 37 CFR 1.84 in a provisional patent would still be considered having the matter in it for the later non-provisional to get the earlier filing date if you need to rely on the drawings for subject matter?

Comment: While drafting a provisional application one should ensure that the subject matter to be claimed by a complete application is “enabled” in the provisional application. Provisionals aren't even required to have drawings. I would just say make the non-provisional drawings as descriptive